# Triggering a function - keybinding CTRL+Z

Tags: jquery, key-bindings

I haven't figured yet how jQuery keybindings work.

I want to trigger a function when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed for example.

These [docs](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) from jQuery's site seems to me, to be dealing with ANY keypress. I'm obviously missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you detect a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
      if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey){
         alert("yahoo!");
         // Do your stuff
      }
});
```

jQuery has some built in stuff as well:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/

**Article:** http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-detect-copy-paste-and-cut-behavior-with-jquery/